# How to take sum of selected rows in mysql using where clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum

This is my table, I want a sum of selected products:

[image]

```
select sum(`price`) from add_product;
```

This query is working fine for the all rows but I want to use where clause like this:

```
select sum(`price`) from add_product where product_id=1233 and product_id=1234;
```

How to do this?

Comment: What's the problem you are facing with that query?

Comment: I think that you need `select sum(price) from add_product where product_id in (1233, 1234);`

Answer (score 2):

first of all,
rectify your query,

you can't have AND between your productIDs,
use OR instead

```
    SELECT 
            SUM(`price`) 
    FROM 
            add_product 
    WHERE
            product_id=1233 OR product_id=1234;
```

you may also use IN clause,

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

OR, if you need a product-wise SUM, then USE GROUP BY,

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm

```
    SELECT 
            product_id, SUM(`price`) totprice
    FROM 
            add_product 
    WHERE
            product_id IN (1233,1234)
    GROUP BY
            product_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using OR, you can use in for multiple values.

```
select sum(`price`) from add_product where product_id in (1233,1234);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using  `BETWEEN` and `AND`**.

For 2 `'product_id'`:

```
SELECT SUM('price') FROM 'add_product' WHERE 'product_id' BETWEEN 1233 AND 1234
```

For 3 `'product_id'` with ascending order:

```
SELECT SUM('price') FROM 'add_product' WHERE 'product_id' BETWEEN 1233 AND 1235 ORDER BY 'product_id' ASC
```